# Html, form with next button going to another form that saves data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Okay so, I'm making a multiple form page and I need it so there is a next button and once you click the button it hides the first form and opens the second, then hides the second shows the third, etc.. And as its doing this its adding previously set values together and will output them after the final form, I don't want it to go onto another page, just stay on the same page.
I have the forms created but for some reason I cant work out the logic for the javascript with adding values and hiding and showing forms, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not then I recommend you look up some javascript tutorials. Stackoverflow shouldn't be used as a free programming service. It's a forum for developers to help each other with a specific programming issue, not to write the entire source code for them.

Comment: Hi Lee, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you could post what you have already found and tried, and any relevant code, for example a minimal working example of what your forms would look like, perhaps in a Plunker https://plnkr.co/. This would make it a lot easier for people to advise on the problem, and you'd be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: For your problem, if you're not already using any Javascript libraries or frameworks, I'd recommend checking out jQuery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ https://jquery.com/ which has a functions for making HTML manipulation straightforward, and start from there.